# Block stored var in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift2

So, I'm doing an async query which returns multiple Worker objects, each Worker has a relation with the WorkerPeriod and I use this relation to do a query, the problem is, the query is async, and when it gets back from the web service, the workerIndex is messed up

```
 workerQuery.whereKey("construction", equalTo: currentConstruction).findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (unsafeWorkers, error) -> Void in
            guard let workers = unsafeWorkers as? [Worker] where error == nil && workers.count == 0 else {
                return
            }

            for var workerIndex = 0; workerIndex < workers.count; workerIndex++ {

                let currentWorker = workers[workerIndex]


                if let periodQuery = WorkerPeriod.query() {
                    periodQuery.whereKey("worker", equalTo: currentWorker)

                    let weakWorkerIndex = workerIndex
                    print("weakWorkerIndex = \(weakWorkerIndex) worker \(workerIndex)")
                    periodQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (unsafeWorkerPeriod, error) -> Void in

                        guard let workerPeriods = unsafeWorkerPeriod as? [WorkerPeriod] where error == nil && workerPeriods.count != 0 else {
                            return
                        }
                        print("block weakWorkerIndex = \(weakWorkerIndex) workerIndex \(workerIndex)")

                        .
                        .

                    })
                }
            }
```

I've tried to create a "weakWorkerIndex" as a let to hold the value as we did in Objective-C with the __block variables, but that doesn't work, the block interaction just ignores the value as you can see in the output:

> ```
> weakWorkerIndex = 0 worker 0
> weakWorkerIndex = 1 worker 1
> block weakWorkerIndex = 0 workerIndex 2
> block weakWorkerIndex = 0 workerIndex 2
> block weakWorkerIndex = 0 workerIndex 2
> ```

By the way: I removed any unnecessary code to simplify the reading.

Answer (score 0):

In the completion handler, you need to ensure that `workerIndex` will be captured *by value*, e.g.:

```
for var workerIndex = 0; workerIndex < 10; workerIndex++ {
    fooAsync { [workerIndex] in
        print("\(workerIndex)")
    }
}
```

See Swift [Capture Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID544)